# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined when eventhandling

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an error with javascript:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`. Can someone tell me why this is happening

Also, there is one more problem. I am trying to make the 2 nav elements inline but it seems to not be working.

If there are any details I left out please tell me

This is my code:

```js
var navlistitems = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-list-items");
for (var i = 0; i < navlistitems.length; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  navlistitems[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    console.log("mouseover");
    navlistitems[i].style.height = "70px";
  });
  navlistitems[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    navlistitems[i].style.height = "50px";
  });
  navlistitems[i].style.width = (document.body.offsetWidth / navlistitems.length) + "px";
  console.log("hi");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#hic {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
}

#nav-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-list-items {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ojas's Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div id="hic">
      <img src="binary-012.jpg" id="hi">
    </div>
    <ul id="nav-list">
      <li class="nav-list-items">Home</li>
      <li class="nav-list-items">Videos</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm a noob when it comes to javascript.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use CSS and `:hover` and flex.

Comment: You must change `navlistitems[i]` to `this` when inside event handler. This is because `i` will change to `.length`;

Comment: SLaks This is just an experiment to test myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot easier to use css selectors instead: *https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp*

Now, why it does not work?

It is because the `i` counter has changed after the for-loop has executed. To make it work, you should use the `this` keyword (which refers to the element being handled) inside the event handler:

```js
var navlistitems = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-list-items");

for (var i = 0; i < navlistitems.length; i++) {
  console.log(i);

  navlistitems[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log(i);
    this.style.height = this.style.lineHeight = "70px";
  });

  navlistitems[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log(i);
    this.style.height = this.style.lineHeight = "50px";
  });

  navlistitems[i].style.width = (document.body.offsetWidth / navlistitems.length) + "px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-list-items {
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ojas's Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul id="nav-list">
      <li class="nav-list-items">Home</li>
      <li class="nav-list-items">Videos</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is just an experiment to try something otherwise I would use css. Do you know why the nav elements are not inline?